# Effect of optical isomerism on colour of transition metal complexes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, color

I know that different stereoisomers of a given transition metal complex (*cis-* and *trans-* forms) have different colours. But do different optical isomers (non-superimposable mirror images) have different colours, or do both optical isomers have the same colour?

Comment: @EdV Do you mean the splitting of the 3d subshell that causes the colour? If so, are you saying that both enantiomers would have the same splitting and so same colour?

Comment: If you ask about *enantiomers* then there's no effect and color is identical.